# webpack-dev-server only proxy "localhost" request

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Webpack-dev-server proxy is broken since I changed Axios base url. It was working fine before I started using `axiosInstance`, so proxying from "localhost:80" toward "localhost:8080". Below are my `webpack.config.js` and the `axiosConfig.js` module. Does anyone understand what's going on?

Please find here a repo with the minimum config reproducing the behaviour: https://github.com/charlycou/webpack-dev-server-proxy-test

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpackConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "main.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    port: 80,
    open: "Chrome",
    proxy: {
      // proxy all webpack dev-server requests starting with /observation to Spring Boot backend (localhost:8080)
      "/observation": "http://localhost:8080",
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [scssLoader, urlLoader, vueLoader]
  },
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()]
};
module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

**axiosConfig.js**

```
import Axios from "axios";
export let axiosInstance = Axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://mydomain.fr:8080',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of you are using 72.0.3626.109 - did you try any other browser?

I cannot use proxy with the latest Chrome but everything is OK with IE11 or FF.
btw I am not talking about Webpack-dev-server exactly but I am struggled with proxy also :(

Comment: I'm not using 72.0.3626.109 and I tried other browser yes. I suggest you to have a look to [the help center - how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You answer isn't helpful but it looks like you're having an issue too! So go ahead and [post your own question!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)